# Reloading a class from controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to be able to reload a class, when a particular option is selected. Unless I reload the class, the changes won't take place. I don't want to restart the entire application for just this purpose.

I came across the `reload!` function for the Rails console, and I was wondering if I could use something like this in my controller (just plain `reload!` is not working).

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need to reload the class? Reloading a class in production is very unorthodox and has a lot of difficult implications. With more information, we may be able to find a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay. I'm having the admin choose if he needs LDAP or Devise for authentication. So he needs to reload the User.rb class when he chooses this. Once he chooses a authentication method he won't be allowed to choose again. I tried to force reload it by using load() method and passing the file path, that kind of works. But I don't think that's the right way to go about it.

Comment: I don't think it's the way. I think you need to use polymorphism or just set two authentication methods for the user and keep the chosen authentication method in the database field. There's no 'right way' to reload a model in production.

Comment: The `reload!`  command is for reloading an Model instance from the database.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out in the comments, reloading a class is not a great idea an probably really confusing for anyone having to maintain the code.

one approach might be to move the implementation-specifics into their own modules and require them based on what the administrator has set. i guess it would be wise to persist this setting (in the database) and have a before-filter setting it up for each call in the controller

```
module LDAP
  def auth
    puts "ldap"
  end
end

module Devise
  def auth
    puts "devise"
  end
end

class User
end

case auth_type
when "devise"
  User.include Devise
when "ldap"
  User.include LDAP
end

User.new.auth
```